# Bulk Upload 1M files with SharePoint PnP PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, pnp-powershell

For the test purposes, we are trying to upload 1 million documents to document library in SharePoint Online. If everything goes really well, it will take approximately 7 days using our current script (see below).

Question: is there a bulk-upload technique we can use to generate a very large number of documents?

**Current script that does not support bulk upload**

```
# =================================================================== #
#              Script for Generating 1M Documents
# =================================================================== #
$SiteURL = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ClassicTeam"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

# =================================================================== #
#              Choose destination library
# =================================================================== #
$DocumentLibrary = 'Shared Documents'

# =================================================================== #
#               Upload 100K Documents
# =================================================================== #
$documentsToGenerate = 1000000

$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath .\SampleFiles

$stopWatch = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
for($i=0;$i -lt $documentsToGenerate; $i++){
    $fileIndex = $i % $files.Count
    $localFile = $files[$fileIndex]
    $fineSuffix = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss_ffff")
    $destinationFileName = $localFile.Name.Split(".")[0] +$fineSuffix + "." + $localFile.Name.Split(".")[1]
    $file = Add-PnPFile -Path $localFile.FullName -Folder $DocumentLibrary -NewFileName $destinationFileName
    Write-host [$i/$documentsToGenerate] " " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-host  $file.Name "uploaded" -ForegroundColor Green 
}
$stopWatch.Stop()
Write-Host Time it took to create $documentsToGenerate documents in the $($SiteURL+$DestinationFolderUrl) -ForegroundColor Cyan
$stopWatch
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

- create a sample document; for instance **demodoc.pdf** in a folder called **DemoFolder**
- use the below PowerShell script to multiply the document demodoc.pdf into one million copies, each with unique names:

```
$NumArray = (1..1000001)
ForEach ($number in $numArray) {
  Copy-Item "C:\Users\admin\Documents\DemoFolder\Demodoc.pdf" `
  -Destination "C:\Users\admin\Documents\DemoFolder\Demodoc$number.pdf"
}
```

- Then use the free [SharePoint migration tool](https://aka.ms/spmt-ga-page) to migrate the one Million documents from the local computer to a document library in SharePoint online.

Obviously, the speed of the migration will depend on a number of factors such as the size of the documents, your internet connection, the speed of the local computer, etc. I tried this in a virtual machine on Microsoft Azure and the entire process was completed in 22 hours.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's a very good option, thank you! I will accept it if there are no other suggestions within a week. And thank you for actually trying to upload a million documents. That's very nice of you!

Comment: Thanks for thanking me. The entire process of generating and uploading the documents to SharePoint online completed in approximately 22 hours.